# How Do I Change Fragment On Button Click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I tried other solutions here but unfortunately couldn't make it! I am new to Android and have almost finished my app, but I am stuck here.

All I want to do is whenever *proceed* button in Home Fragment is clicked, it moves to the next SGPA fragment.

This is how your code looks now :

```
public class home extends Fragment {

//String Values For Courses and Semesters
String [] courses = {"BBA","BCA","B.Com Honours","B.Ed","B & I"};
String [] semesters = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"};
public home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Course Spinner
    View c = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    Spinner courseSpinner = (Spinner) c.findViewById(R.id.courses);
    ArrayAdapter<String> LTRadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courses);
    LTRadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    courseSpinner.setAdapter(LTRadapter);

    //Semester Spinner
    Spinner Spinner = (Spinner) c.findViewById(R.id.semester);
    ArrayAdapter<String> LTRadapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, semesters);
    LTRadapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    Spinner.setAdapter(LTRadapter1);

    //Proceed Button
    Button b = (Button) c.findViewById(R.id.proceedbtn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
                fragment = new sgpa();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    });
    return c;
}
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.sgpaFragment, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: And... you just expect people to finish your project for you?

Comment: I am just asking for help!!! If i wanted people to finish it i wouldn't have done so much work!! I just provided all the code so that i can easily understand what i have to code and where....

Comment: Why arent you just using your view pager? When you click the button on the home fragment you want it to goto the next page right?@Azzler

Comment: Hey thanks for taking some time @cunniemm but i am new to android... If you can guide me that will be really appreciable... And yes... I want the same....

Comment: I did not edit any sentences? I simply shifted code over to make the code look more clean? @halfer

Comment: @halfer Hey man if you look in the onCreateView, that is the only section that I touched! I didn't edit anywhere else. That is really weird that its saying I did that??

Comment: @cunniemm: ah OK, my apologies - I will get it reported. I don't know how people can use the review system here if edits are not being attributed correctly.

Comment: @halfer No worries and good!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Just make sure that you give your home fragment an id, so you can replace it, you have the right idea in your replaceFragment method just not doing the transaction right!

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.home, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. So i will also have to add onClick property on proceed button... Right??

Comment: alright i pasted this code but there are three errors like it can't resolve symbols temp, viewpager and setCurrentItem. It also says that setCurrentItem is never used...

Comment: @Azzler Check Fix, make sure you are putting the set current item in the right spot, Try pasting it right after you setup your viewPager! And yes!

Comment: @Azzler Remember you're pasting the setCurrentItem method in your MainActivity.

Comment: hey @cunniemm, all those errors are fixed now, but now it's saying that:

Required : android.support.v4.application something like this
AND Found : anddroid.application something

However i am using the same package that is required... :O I can't get what's wrong....

Comment: @Azzler does it fail when you try and run it?

Comment: @Azzler just make sure you have everything imported, once you goto the error hold alt+enter and then you should be able to auto complete the fix for the error if that doesn't work, I'll take re-write your code a little

Comment: I tried that @cunniemm but unfortunately that didn't work. I don't know what's being wrong with it as I have used the same package that is required...

Comment: hey @cunniemm, Me and one of my friend made some changes in your code which took off all the errors and warnings but the issue that we are facing now is that the proceed button is doing nothing at all... I have edited the question with the new code. Please have a look. You are my saviour!!! lol... :P

Comment: @Azzler I don't have my computer! So I'm doing this from my phone I think all you needed to do was change the id of what you were replacing and pass your replaceFragment method your sgpa fragment!

Comment: @Azzler Any luck?